# Transposition not diagonalizable in characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

In [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1035659/11619) it was proved that transposition as a linear map is diagonalizable. This, however, does not hold when we are working over a field of characteristic 2. I suppose the proof of this can be a bit tricky. Any hints?

Comment: Not sure about tricky: All the eigenvalues are identical, hence it can only be diagonalizable if it is diagonal, which it is not.

Comment: Notice that in a field of characteristic 2 the only diagonal matrix which is invertible is the identity.

Comment: @Valentin That is for the field with $2$ elements, not an arbitary field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Yeah, an arbitrary field of characteristic 2.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft how does it follow eigenvalues are identical?

Comment: The transformation squares to the identity, so eigenvalues must be roots of $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)^2$.

Comment: Glad to see you followed the suggestion of asking this in a new thread. I added a link to it here because that helps readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the transposition transformation, and let $I$ denote the identity transformation.  We note that
$$
(T - I)^2 = T^2 - 2T + I = T^2 -  I = 0
$$
It follows that the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $x-1$, which is to say that $1$ is its only eigenvalue.  If $T$ is diagonalizable, it must then be equal to the identity.

Since $T$ is not the identity transformation, it is not diagonalizable.